# When mutating a module object, why are curly brace imports not changed?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, create-react-app

I'm playing around with tidying up a code base that does some direct module mutations, rather than using any mocking behaviour, and I've noticed something odd.

If I, starting with a fresh create-react-app do something like this in a test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
import lodash from "lodash"; 
test('renders learn react link', () => {

  // Directly mutating the module
  React.useContext = jest.fn();
  React.foo = "foo";
  lodash.drop = jest.fn(); 

  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Then when I later go to use these mutations:

```
import React, {useContext, foo} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import lodash, {drop} from "lodash"; 
function App() {


  console.log(useContext, React.useContext, foo, React.foo );
  console.log(drop, lodash.drop); 
  // The rest doesn't matter.
```

Then what we can see is that the `React.useContext`, `React.foo`, `lodash.drop` will print the jest mock function, whereas the `useContext`, `foo` and `drop` will print the original object.

Full print:

```
  console.log src/App.js:8
    [Function: useContext] [Function: mockConstructor] {
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
      getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
    } undefined foo

  console.log src/App.js:9
    [Function: drop] [Function: mockConstructor] {
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
      getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
    }

 PASS  src/App.test.js (6.875s)
  ✓ renders learn react link (304ms)
```

Why is this?

I assume that it's something to do with the way import/require is resolving the imports, and that doing:

```
import React, {useContext} from "react"
```

is **not** the same as doing

```
import React from "react"; 
const {useContext} = React
```

As counter-intuitive as that is.

Comment: You are right, it's not the same. Why should it? The first imports the **default** export and the **named export** `useContext` from `react`. The second imports the default export and then, assuming the value of the default export is an object, takes the property `useContext` from that object. Or as code: `export default {}; export const useContenxt = 42;` vs `export default {useContext: 42}`. If you come from CommonJS modules than I could see how this might be confusing, but ES module work differently (and are less confusing IMO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to When the variables/constants are created.

Import is "executed" before you mutate your object and the constant foo, is then created before you mutate React.foo.

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
const a = obj.a; // import
obj.a = 42; // your mock injection

console.log(a); // it will keep returning 1
```

The way this is handled, is that when `a` (`foo` or `useContext` in your example) is created, it points to the position of memory hold by `obj.a`, which contains a `1` in the moment of creation. Then `obj.a` points to a new position of memory where a `42` is stored, but `obj.a` and `a` are independent one to another.

In your case my recommendation is to use a Dependency Injection solution.

Either App receive a parameter for which dependency it needs, and then you mock it in the test. `<App foo={myFooMock} />` or another usual solution is to sent a context, and have a context creator for Tests with mocks and a context creator for production app.

```js
const myMockedContext = {foo: 'foo', useContext: jest.fn()};
const { getByText } = render(<App context={myMockedContext} />);
```

Normally you would want to have as much of your real code in your test as possible, all your business logic so that your test fail as soon as there are changes in interfaces or error in type returns or any other unexpected behaviour among your different areas of code.

But this is an ongoing discussion between Mockist and Classists in the TDD community.

HTH