# How to modify module.exports from within a function?

Tags: javascript, module.exports

So what I mean is that I want to export a certain object within a function.

```
async function Set(x) {
  module.exports["x"] = x
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, and it becomes undefined, can you guys help?

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    var args = message.content.split(/[ ]+/)
    const Cargs = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/[ ]+/);
    const command = Cargs.shift().toUpperCase();

    if (client.commands.get(command)) {
        await Set(message)
        client.commands.get(command).execute()
    }
})
```

Comment: What's the context that you would want to do this? ie. Where are you calling this function `Set`?

Comment: I want to do this because I have another function where it repeatedly needs to change the export.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code that would be calling this code?

Comment: I just edited my code, the 4 to the last line is where I call Set.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to do here. Ok, I can see you are calling the `Set` function, but then where are you expecting the import to have changed?

Comment: This is a Discord bot uring a File command Handler, and I want to pass through the message when the command file is ran.

Comment: Does this here look like what you want to do? https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-darkness-setjk?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Yep! The libary I'm using generated a new object each time a new message is sent, I want to export that message object so my other .js files can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, what you want to do is perfectly possible.

However, you need to be careful about the nature of modules and object references.

For example, say we have your module file:

module.js

```
const setFn = (x) => {
  module.exports.x = x; 
}

module.exports = {
  x: "hello", 
  setFn, 

}
```

And you are going to consume the export `x` as well as modify with the `setFn` function in index.js

This here will not work correctly:

index.js

```
const {x, setFn} = require("./module"); 

console.log("Start");  //Start
console.log(x);        //hello
setFn("world");
console.log(x);        //hello - why hasn't it changed? 
console.log("end");    //end
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-darkness-setjk?file=/src/index.js)

This is because you have imported a *direct reference* to the `x` variable, which has the value "hello" at the time that required it.

When you later mutate the module via the `setFn` function, you still retain that reference to the old "hello" value.

However, if you change the code to this:

```
const module = require("./module"); 

console.log("Start");  //Start
console.log(module.x);        //hello
module.setFn("world");
console.log(module.x);        //world
console.log("end");    //end
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-dawn-r3wbm?file=/src/index.js)

Then the code works.

This is because instead of importing direct references to `x` and `setFn` you have imported a reference to the module itself.

When you mutate the module itself, and later refer to `module.x` again, you can see the updated value.

I recommend also looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628983/1068446). This one deals with ESM modules, but I think the lesson is the same.

In terms of what you're doing though - I'm not sure how useful this is, because for this to work it really requires that the consumer of the module imports the whole module and always references the properties via `module.x`.

Also, are you sure the value you are passing into the `Set` function isn't undefined?

Comment: Thank you so much for your knowledge! I've been trying to do this for a very long time!